# Indexing Issue after Update Magento 1 to Magento 2

Tags: magento2, reindex, data-migration

After I had migrated my website from magento 1.9 to magento 2.1,
Everything is working fine except for a few bugs

i get this while running `php bin/magento indexer:reindex`

```
    SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails 
    (`thebeautyfloor1`.`catalogrule_group_website`, CONSTRAINT `CATALOGRULE_GROUP_WEBSITE_RULE_ID_CATALOGRULE_RULE_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`rule_id`) REFERENCES `catalogrule` (`rule_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE), 
query was: 
INSERT INTO `catalogrule_group_website` (`rule_id`, `customer_group_id`, `website_id`) 
SELECT DISTINCT  `catalogrule_product`.`rule_id`, `catalogrule_product`.`customer_group_id`, `catalogrule_product`.`website_id` FROM `catalogrule_product` 
WHERE (1527155869 >= from_time
 AND ((1527155869 <= to_time AND to_time > 0) OR to_time = 0)) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `rule_id` = VALUES(`rule_id`), `customer_group_id` = VALUES(`customer_group_id`), 
`website_id` = VALUES(`website_id`)
```

And when i try to change the Theme i get the ERROR

**Requested store is not found**

Any guidance will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete lingering items

```
DELETE FROM catalogrule_product WHERE rule_id NOT IN (SELECT rule_id FROM catalogrule)
```

After that, try to add some missing constraints to the table.

```
ALTER TABLE `catalogrule_product` ADD CONSTRAINT `CATALOGRULE_PRODUCT_PRODUCT_ID_CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_ENTITY_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE `catalogrule_product` ADD CONSTRAINT `CATALOGRULE_PRODUCT_CUSTOMER_GRP_ID_CUSTOMER_GRP_CUSTOMER_GRP_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`customer_group_id`) REFERENCES `customer_group` (`customer_group_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE `catalogrule_product` ADD CONSTRAINT `CATALOGRULE_PRODUCT_RULE_ID_CATALOGRULE_RULE_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`rule_id`) REFERENCES `catalogrule` (`rule_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE `catalogrule_product` ADD CONSTRAINT `CATALOGRULE_PRODUCT_WEBSITE_ID_STORE_WEBSITE_WEBSITE_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`website_id`) REFERENCES `store_website` (`website_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```